# Why to use full 2-part table names in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-schema

I asked a previous question about shortening the table names in SQL Server, and came across this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/dn148262(v=msdn.10), which suggests using the fully scoped table name, such as `[dbo].[Title]` instead of just `Title`.

What is the reason to use the fully-scoped table name? I've never come across a place where there have been multiple identical table names in a database (actually I didn't even think it's possible?), so for me that seems like it's unnecessary, but I'm very new to SQL Server, so was wondering why this is the preferred way to do it.

Comment: What if you have `dbo.Title` and `MySchema.Title`? If you write just `Title` which one you mean?

Comment: @Sami does SQL server have multiple schemes within a database connection? If so, what's a good reference link to see how it's structured (I mostly use MySQL for database stuff).

Comment: It is in the documentation you provided: "For ad-hoc queries and prepared statements, query reuse will not occur if object name resolution needs to occur. Queries that are contained within stored procedures, functions, and triggers do not have this limitation. 
However, in general it should be noted that the use of two-part object names (that is, schema.object) provides more opportunities for plan reuse and should be encouraged.
"

Comment: @David542 SQL Server allow you to create multiple schemes, and in this case it will use the default schema `dbo` usually. [here is a simple example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=592786fdefdb0f3e7371a8a1f6a7df77). You could always see the [docs online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Sami here is what it says about databases: `A database in SQL Server is made up of a collection of tables that stores a specific set of structured data. A table contains a collection of rows, also referred to as records or tuples, and columns, also referred to as attributes. Each column in the table is designed to store a certain type of information, for example, dates, names, dollar amounts, and numbers.`. Where do schemas come into play then? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/databases?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @David542 That's in general, it's just an overview about **databases** in general. If we're going to talk about _"Why didn't mention schemas?"_ then why didn't mention indexes too :)

Comment: @Sami that's actually pretty neat then if I'm understanding it correctly -- basically a schema is a way to 'bucket' a number of tables to make granting permissions more easy:  for example, instead of granting 20 tables to one user, I could just grant them access to a particular schema -- is that more or less correct?

Comment: And you get a minor performance improvement if you resolve the schema because then SQL Server doesn't have to.

Comment: Actually a full name is 4 parts: ServerName.DatabaseName.SchemeName.TableName. When you omit first 2, current server and database is assumed.

Comment: When importing data and transforming it to load into the base tables, it can be convenient to stage the data in a set of tables in a staging schema, using tables with the same structure and names as the base tables.  This makes it easy to use the information_schema views to automate the process of moving data from staging tables to base tables.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation that you gave link to:

"For ad-hoc queries and prepared statements, query reuse will not occur if object name resolution needs to occur. Queries that are contained within stored procedures, functions, and triggers do not have this limitation. 
However, in general it should be noted that the use of two-part object names (that is, schema.object) provides more opportunities for plan reuse and should be encouraged."

*query reuse will not occur if object name resolution needs to occur*

Comment: could you please elaborate on that? For example, how is object name resolution determined? Other than query reuse, is there any other reason.

Comment: Wherever a name is needed, it needs to be resolved, ie: in a select, insert, update ... You are assuming there would be a single scheme, but that is not the case (check AdventureWorks sample database as a an example).